# Is there a theory of "derived extensions"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, exact-sequence

Given an exact sequence of groups
$$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow K\rightarrow 1$$
we call $G$ a *central extension* of $K$ by $N$ if the image of $N$ is contained in the center of $G$. Central extensions of a group $K$ by another group $N$ have been classified and are in bijection with the 2-cocycles from $K$ to $N$.

Now, given an an exact sequence of groups
$$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow K\rightarrow 1$$
let's call $G$ a *derived extension* of $K$ by $N$ if the image of $N$ *contains* the derived subgroup of $G$.

> Is there already a theory built around these kind of exact sequences? Is there any literature on these "derived extensions"?

I haven't been able to find anything on them, but I may be searching for the incorrect term.

> If there isn't already a theory, can we classify the possible derived extensions of an arbitrary abelian group $K$ by another group $N$?

Some trivial examples are
$$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow N\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 1\quad\text{ and }\quad 1\rightarrow 1\rightarrow K\rightarrow K\rightarrow 1$$

for arbitrary $N$ and abelian $K$.

Some less trivial examples are
$$1\rightarrow A_n\rightarrow S_n\rightarrow Z_2\rightarrow 1\quad\text{ and }\quad 1\rightarrow V_4\rightarrow A_4\rightarrow Z_3\rightarrow 1$$

Another example is
$$1\rightarrow A_n\rightarrow A_n\times Z_2\rightarrow Z_2\rightarrow 1$$
for $n\geq 5$. So we see that two derived extensions of a group by another need not be isomorphic since $S_n$ is not a direct product of $Z_2$ and $A_n$ for $n\geq 4$.

More generally,
$$1\rightarrow P\rightarrow P\times A\rightarrow A\rightarrow 1$$
is a derived extension for a perfect group $P$ and an abelian group $A$ since the commutator subgroup of a product is a product of the commutator subgroups.

Clearly, given the trivial group and a perfect group $N$ there is only one derived extension of $1$ by $N$; and that is $N$ itself. But what about in general? I'm wondering if there's a similar characterization as in central extensions or (right-)split extensions.

Any help or reference is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if $N$ contains the derived subgroup of $G$, the group $K \cong G/N$ must be abelian. Conversely, if $K$ is abelian, then the image of $N$ must contain the derived subgroup of $G$. So this new concept is just short exact sequences where $K$ is abelian.

Comment: I'm asking if we can characterize the possible $G$ given $K$ and $N$. We don't know what $G$ is here.

Comment: As Alastair says, the condition is equivalent to the condition that $K$ is abelian, so you're just asking about how to classify not-necessarily-central extensions. The answer is given by the nonabelian cohomology of $K$ with coefficients in the automorphism $2$-group $\text{Aut}(N)$ of $N$; the extra hypothesis that $K$ is abelian makes no particular difference. I don't know a reference where this is explained though.